# Downloading from FTP using wildcards on Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp

We access an FTP site that has files on it, saved daily with the date in the form YYYYMMDD.
What I am trying to do is run FTP in the command line to download all files with YYYYMMDD in them. Currently I have the following going through the FTP:

```
binary
cd /Outgoing
lcd c:\temp\FTP\files
mput *20140312*
Quit
```

Unfortunately, when I get to the line `mput *20140312*`, I get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`. When I run it as `mput 946_20140312_040000.csv` it works fine. I am running ftp with the -i and -g commands to allow for wildcards and to do it without prompts.

Ideally, I would like to get this working with the built in FTP functionality and would install another command line client as a last resort.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the `-g` away it disables globbing which means that the wildcaracter expansion is also turned off. Have a look here http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ftp

Comment: Ah, for some reason I had it in my head that it was off by default. Thanks